# DIR loop with specific sheet names

Tags: vba, loops

I have 5 files in a folder. I need to split a sheet called Marrs Upload into a separate worksheet.

I've managed to get it to work for the first file but after that it comes up with the "Run Time error: 9 Subscript out of range" message.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub Hello()

StrFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" 'Get path name
GetFullFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'File name
sFilename = Left(GetFullFile, (InStr(GetFullFile, ".") - 1)) 'Fine the . and
i = 1 'Part of the name counter
ExportFile = StrFile + "Import to Marrs\"
SaveAsFileName = "Marrs Upload " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy ") ' Saves the filename Marrs Upload (Date) followed by counter
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strFilename = Dir(StrFile)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' exit if no files in folder
Do Until strFilename = ""
        Sheets("Marrs Upload").Move ' Moves Marrs Upload tab
        ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ExportFile & SaveAsFileName & i)
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
        'ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
        i = i + 1
        strFilename = Dir()


Loop
End Sub
```

I've tried most things and cannot get any further.

Kind Regards,
Ashley

I've added to original code to only work if a certain sheet name exists.

```
Sub Hello()



StrFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" 'Get path name
GetFullFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'File name
sFileName = Left(GetFullFile, (InStr(GetFullFile, ".") - 1)) 'Find the . and returns only file name minus extension
i = 1 'Counter
ExportFile = StrFile + "Import to Marrs\" 'Saves new worksheet in a specific folder
SaveAsFileName = "Marrs Upload " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy ") ' Saves the filename Marrs Upload (Date) followed by counter
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Don't display alerts "Overwrite, ect"



StrFileName = Dir(StrFile) 'No extension as can be a combination of .xlsm and .xls

Do While Len(StrFileName) > 0 'Loop when files are in DIR
    If CheckSheet("Marrs Upload") Then 'if workseet contains a tab called "Marrs Upload" then continue.
            Sheets("Marrs Upload").Move ' Moves Marrs Upload tab
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ExportFile & SaveAsFileName & i) 'Save worksheet as Marrs Upload (Date) (Counter)
            ActiveWorkbook.Close (False) 'Don't need to save original file (Audit Trail)
            i = i + 1 'Increase counter by 1
    End If
StrFileName = Dir() 'used when worksheet doesn't contain sheet called "Marrs Upload"
Loop

End Sub

Function CheckSheet(ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean

Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim bReturn As Boolean

For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then

        bReturn = True
        Exit For

    End If

Next oSheet

CheckSheet = bReturn

End Function
```

Kind Regards,
Ashley

Comment: Is the workbook with the macro saved in the folder containing the files to be processed? Does the Dir() loop need to skip that workbook when moving the sheets?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Tested, and works for me.

```
Sub Hello()

Dim SourceFolder As String, DestFolder As String
Dim f As String, SaveAsFileName As String, sFileName As String
Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook

    '*** if ActiveWorkbook has the macro, safer to use ThisWorkbook
    SourceFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
    DestFolder = SourceFolder & "Import to Marrs\"

    '*** what are you doing with this?
    sFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
                     (InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1))

    ' Saves the filename Marrs Upload (Date) followed by counter
    SaveAsFileName = "Marrs Upload " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy ")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    i = 1 'Part of the name counter
    f = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.xls*") '*** use wildcard for XL files only

    Do While Len(f) > 0

        Debug.Print f

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(SourceFolder & f)

        If CheckSheet(wb, "Marrs Upload") Then
            wb.Sheets("Marrs Upload").Move ' Moves Marrs Upload tab
            '*** the wb with the moved sheet is now active: save it
            With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs (DestFolder & SaveAsFileName & i)
            .Close True
            End With
            i = i + 1
        End If
        wb.Close False '***close the one we just opened. Not saving?
        f = Dir() '*** next file
    Loop

End Sub


Function CheckSheet(wb as WorkBook, ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    For Each oSheet In wb.WorkSheets
        If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then
            bReturn = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oSheet

    CheckSheet = bReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I've editted the original question as I needed to loop through all the files but only work when a certain tab is there.

Comment: In your updated code you're calling Dir() twice: once when the sheet is found and then again just before the `Loop` statement: you only need that second one.

Comment: I've removed the First DIR() now. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. It's still not working.
It continues through the IF expression as if there isn't a sheet with the name "Marrs Upload".
All files in folder has the sheet names "Marrs Upload"

Comment: See my updated answer. Make sure you're not missing actually opening the file you want to copy the sheet from.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that code posted by @TimWilliams does not work. Are you sure you have stated your problem correctly?

Comment: @Remou - you might be surpised how often I post stuff which doesn't *exactly* work! However I typically add "Untested" unless I actually did test it first.  If it's something requiring some setup (like creating a folder structure) then typically I don't test.

Comment: My folder structure setup is C:\Users\Ashley\Documents\Ashley's\Work\Macros for the main spreadsheet using the macro. The other files are also in this folder. The separated sheets need to go into C:\Users\Ashley\Documents\Ashley's\Work\Macros\Import to Marrs.
I've tried running the Macro step-by-step but the Worksheet.open stops this function

Comment: If you can upload your file somewhere I will try to take a look.